# How to send a post request with link attribute?

Tags: java, html

I have a requirement that a user can register with the the services what he can provide. Need to send a mail to the administrator with a link for approval. If the admin approved it means need to make the entries in database for that user. This data i will collect from request body from client. When the admin approves it, need to get the data back for the data storage. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by saving a hashvalue token to database, and check with these token in callback.

I Think This may help you :[Verify User by Email](http://www.baeldung.com/registration-verify-user-by-email).

Please Check the link.